# Requiring, for a protocol, that an instance variable conform to a protocol ; rather than have a specific type

Tags: swift, protocols

As part of a custom `Coder`, I convert both `Float` and `Double` in the exact same way :

```swift
static func encode(_ value : Double) -> Data {
    withUnsafeBytes(of: value.bitPattern.bigEndian) { Data($0) }
}

static func encode(_ value : Float) -> Data {
    withUnsafeBytes(of: value.bitPattern.bigEndian) { Data($0) }
}
```

I thought that instead I could require that `value` would conform to a protocol, and since the `FloatingPoint` protocol does not guarantee the presence of `bitPattern`, I thought I would make my own :

```swift
protocol CompatibleFloatingPoint {
    var bitPattern : FixedWidthInteger { get }
}
```

This, however, gives the following error :
`Protocol 'FixedWidthInteger' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

However, I cannot replace `FixedWidthInteger` with a specific type, as `Double.bitPattern` is a `UInt64` and `Float.bitPattern` is a `UInt32`

What is the proper syntax to require that `bitPattern` conform to the `FixedWidthInteger` protocol without forcing it to have a specific type ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is an associated type. This means exactly what you've described (the required type conforms to a protocol rather than being the existential of that protocol):

```
protocol CompatibleFloatingPoint {
    associatedtype BitPattern: FixedWidthInteger
    var bitPattern : BitPattern { get }
}

extension Float: CompatibleFloatingPoint {}
extension Double: CompatibleFloatingPoint {}
```

For more details, see [Associated Types](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html#ID189) in the Swift Programming Language.

Comment: Thank you ! That is exactly what I needed 